# when using capybara is there a way to print out to a file what page of the app you're supposed to be on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

when using capybara is there a way to print out to a file what page of the app you're supposed to be on?

For example if I'm supposed to go from the root page to the index to the show is there a way to have that printed out to a file?

Comment: save_and_open_page is exactly what I needed! that rocks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Capybara Readme](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#debugging):

### Debugging

It can be useful to take a snapshot of the page as it currently is and take a look at it:

```
save_and_open_page
```

You can also retrieve the current state of the DOM as a string using page.html.

```
print page.html
```

This is mostly useful for debugging. You should avoid testing against the contents of page.html and use the more expressive finder methods instead.

Finally, in drivers that support it, you can save a screenshot:

```
page.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
```

---

You should be able to print to a file in Rails with

```
File.open((Rails.root.join('capybara', 'capybara.html'), 'w') do |f|
  f.puts page.html
end
```

Haven't done it yet, so please report back.

Answer (score 3):

Just use: `save_and_open_page`

[Capybara Reference](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/d/david-capybara-0.3.9.1/Capybara/SaveAndOpenPage.html)

For that to work you'll have to add the gem **launchy** to your Gemfile inside the test group:

```
group :test do
  ...
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'launchy'
end
```